# Is there a way to use the Intel GPU when running Windows 7 from Bootcamp?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, macos, gpu

Alright, so the problem I'm currently facing is that when I run Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro (Early 2011, 15" 2.2GHz CPU) with OS X 10.8,

I used Bootcamp 5 to install Windows 7.

Windows does not recognize the Intel HD graphics 3000 GPU but it does with my second GPU AMD Radeon HD 6750M.

The Error is:

> "This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing
>   the software."

I tired following without success:

- I downloaded all of the drivers I would require for me, and moved
  them to my flash drive. Contained on that flash drive is the driver
  for the Intel Graphics chip, though when I run the setup it displays:
  "This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing
  the software."
- Also, I have tried to add the hardware from Device Manager with no
  luck. I just find it hard to believe that apple would supply the
  driver, but not allow access to the Intel GPU.
- Resetting PRAM and SMC has no impact.

Answer (score 1):

This accepted answer is no longer correct for newer models. Newer Macs don't let you use the Intel Graphics Card on Windows. [Here is a thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7996952) with explanations and a really complicated workaround.

---

For older Macs:

Let's start with [this from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx?lang=eng).

Then go here and select the [right driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop%20graphics%20drivers&ProductProduct=2nd%20Generation%20Intel%C2%AE%20Core%E2%84%A2%20Processors%20with%20Intel%C2%AE%20HD%20Graphics%203000/2000&ProdId=3319&LineId=1101&FamilyId=3).

EDIT: Since we still have the problem lets go back to BASICS:

[What do I need to install Windows 7](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3986?viewlocale=en_US)?

This table shows the [required Bootcamp version](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638).

Try removing application receipts:

If you're reinstalling an application or updating an existing one, try removing the application's receipts. Look for any receipts that bear the name of the application in the the Receipts folder inside of the main Library folder (/Library/Receipts) and move them elsewhere. Then try installing or updating your software again.

Comment: Just doing some housekeeping before we continue, since unfortunately you do have enough points to move this to our Chat session. Please delete any comment (yours) that do not make sense anymore. Just gave you 5 points for good cooperation.

Comment: PS, I am just reading an interesting discussion here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2770866?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: Interesting discussion, but it looks like it's going nowhere..

Comment: Sadly it does ! So far it looks like there is no way to make the Windows accept the HD 3000.

Comment: I am clueless but checking your http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237 would not harm.